# ¿Cómo aplicar estilo a barra de desplazamiento textarea?

Tags: html5, css3

Existe alguna forma de crear estilos a la barra de desplazamiento de un textarea que sea compatible con todos los navegadores.

Este es mi diseño que estoy implementando en el textarea pero la barra de desplazamiento le quita el buen estilo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
textarea {
  width:80%;
  height:150px;
  padding:15px;
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: justify;
  outline: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: "raleway";
  resize: none;
  /*border: 1px dotted #000099;
  background-color: rgba(82, 56, 76, 0.15);*/
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Mensaje..."></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Los estilos `CSS` de la barra de desplazamiento son una rareza inventada por los desarrolladores de `Microsoft`. **No forman parte del estándar `W3C` para `CSS`** y por lo tanto la mayoría de los navegadores simplemente los ignoran.

Sin embargo, existen algunas sentencias para hacerlo, aunque no hay ninguna garantía que funcionen entre diferentes navegadores([mejor detalladas aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150577/4987172)).

Existen algunas librerías que solucionan el problema:

- [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar)
- [malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin)
- [Optiscroll](https://github.com/wilsonfletcher/Optiscroll)

  ...

Answer (score 0):

Este es una librería jQuery con la que alguna vez trabaje y esta soportada para la mayoría de navegadores. Espero te sirva.

[Descarga jQuery.NiceScroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll)

Answer (score 0):

esta es una forma para cambiarle el color y las dimensiones de la barra de desplazamiento:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
   background: #090909;
   width: 13px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: #252525;
    width: 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    background-color: #333;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
    background-color: #555;
}
```

eso va en css